# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline cmd.exe exited with code '1'

Tags: cmd, azure-pipelines

I'm currently looking to do a "If the service doesn't exist, create it" in my DevOps  Pipeline, but I'm consistently getting the " cmd.exe exited with code '1' " error...

The problem I have, is that when I run this exact code in a batch file, it works without any errors:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Create install script for windows service communication
  inputs:
    script: >-
      (
      echo @echo off

      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
      
      set _ServiceName=SalesOrderManagement.WindowsService1

      sc query %_ServiceName% | find "does not exist" >nul
      if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 sc.exe create %_ServiceName% binpath= C:\appservice\SalesOrderManagement.WindowsService\SalesOrderManagement.WindowsService.exe displayname= %_ServiceName%
      
      sc.exe description %_ServiceName% $(Build.BuildNumber)

      net start %_ServiceName%

      ) > C:\appservice\SalesOrderManagement.WindowsService\ServiceStart.txt
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks so much... in the end, I was debugging the wrong step (copy and paste fail), but these pointers helped me resolve another issue that cropped up later on.

Comment: what was the problem and what fixed it exactly? I'm not debugging the wrong step for sure but still getting this error even though nothing inside the script returns error

Comment: What I discovered is that, sometimes you need to explicitly end with "exit 0", no idea why, but the task will be marked as "in error" if you don't

Comment: Thank you @the_hoof, it worked for me too. A really strange way of throwing error for azure.

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos I think it's a PowerShell handler issue... but glad it worked

Comment: adding "exit 0" can works